# How to use localized strings in the PHP code using Laravel?

Tags: php, localization, laravel-5.3

I use Laravel Framework, and found this issue:

```
$var = ($userdata->age > 18 ? 'OK' : '@lang("basics.no_access")');
```

Of course I want to get the nice text from `resources/lang/en/basics.php` and not echo the '@lang("basics.no_access")' text.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`@lang` works only within blade templates.

[Use `lang::get()`](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/249/getting-the-translation-for-a-key) which is the correct way to look up a language key outside a template:

> When you pass `Lang::get()` a key, it looks up the key in the translation tables for the current locale. If no match is found, the original key is returned.

Comment: Looking good, but now I get FatalErrorException in MyController.php line 30: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Lang' not found. How can I get this Lang controller? Sorry, I'm really newbie for Laravel.

Comment: Sorry, `use Lang;` give me the soution :)